# Canvas images not displaying upon page load

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

We have a canvas element where 5 images are being displayed, but when we open the page, it does not display them correctly. Some are not even loaded at all and others are displayed wrongly.

The first image takes up the whole canvas, while the other 4 should be displayed on top of that image. Like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1XSC.png

Here is the Javascript code:

```
var stage;
function init() {
stage = new createjs.Stage("kort");

addImage("https://videnpiloterne.dk/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/rksk-web.png", 0.65, 0.65, 0, 0);
addImage("http://www.gratisskole.dk/sdata/minipic/008/00887-300.png", 0.25, 0.25, 250, 250);
addImage("https://img.clipartfest.com/d57989e2bab24e922d1777fb69ffcccc_windmill20clipart-clipart-wind-mill-clip-art_199-199.png", 0.4, 0.4, 335, 100);
addImage("http://www.gratisskole.dk/sdata/minipic/000/00068-300.png", 0.25, 0.25, 30, 375);
addImage("http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/RTd/GoM/RTdGoMGT9.svg", 0.225, 0.225, 100, 75);

function addImage(url, scaleX, scaleY, locX, locY) {
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = url;
    image.onload = function() { 
        var imageBitmap = new createjs.Bitmap(image);
        imageBitmap.x = locX;
        imageBitmap.y = locY;
        imageBitmap.scaleX=scaleX;
        imageBitmap.scaleY=scaleY;
        stage.addChild(imageBitmap);
        stage.update();
    }    
} 
}
```

Comment: **developer** tools console ... anything interesting there?

Comment: `z-indez` in `css` might help you..